# Audio extraction in xamarin from mp4 file

Tags: android, xamarin, ffmpeg

I need to convert an mp4 (or any other video format) to mp3 or wav file. I am using C# Xamarin.Forms. Any library I used either doesn't work for me, or isn't compatible with android. I have tried using Xamarin.Android.FFMpeg and Xobe.FFMpeg. I repost this because it was marked as duplicate and I clearly stated that that solution isn't working for me. This is the post that was flagged as duplicate: How can I extract the audio out of a video file? (android) . Please, I tried it but it just gives me the "Downloading Video Converter" dialog with a progress bar when I try to run the code in the solution, Also, it doesn't even extract the audio so after the user waits such a long time, it turned out as a waste of time. Thanks in advance! :)

### EDIT 1:

This is the code I am using:

```
private async Task<string> ExtractAudioAsync(string path, Action<string> logger = null,
        Action<int, int> onProgress = null)
    {
        List<string> cmd = new List<string>();
        cmd.Add("-i");
        cmd.Add(path + ".mp4");
        cmd.Add("-vn");
        cmd.Add("-acodec");
        cmd.Add("copy");
        cmd.Add(path + ".mp3");
        string cmdParams = string.Join(' ', cmd);
        await FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFMpegLibrary.Run(Context, cmdParams);

        return path + ".mp3";
    }
```

There are no exceptions thrown. When the Run method is called it just shows on the application the following dialog:

### [image: the dialog]

After that, it just closes the dialog and goes to the return line without even extracting the audio out of the video. Even if I run this code again it does the same thing, downloading it again.

### EDIT 2:

I tried adding the `-report` option but it just did the same thing and did not save any log file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: review the `logcat` output for the errors

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log

Comment: There is no output. There is no error occurring, it just shows the dialog for some reason, doesn't matter what I do, even if I run it again it downloads it again